# BeautifulSoup returns only text of a tag when selecting any tag by value, was expecting to get full tag returned

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I try to select tags based on the 'string' value of the tag, but without specifying a specific tag, I get only the String value returned and not the full tag.
If I specify a tag along with a String value then the full tag is returned.

For example:

```
url = 'https://www.betts.com.au/item/39613-shifter.html?colour=black'
bs = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, features="html.parser")
print(bs.find_all(string='SHIFTER'))
print(bs.find_all('h1', string='SHIFTER'))
```

The output looks like this:

```
['SHIFTER', 'SHIFTER']
[<h1 class="wdj-item-descrpition-h1">SHIFTER</h1>]
```

I was hoping to get the full tag with the first `.find_all()`. Am I doing it wrong, or is it not possible?

I've been reading the [docs here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all), and they don't have any examples that are exactly the same, but it seems to suggest the find_all() should result a tag, rather than just text - hence I'm a bit confused about why I only get text values returned.

Comment: Specifying string will imho return just the text

Comment: Try: soup.find_all('h1')

Comment: @Pitto ... I don't want to limit it to h1, would like to be able to get any tag that has the matching text/string

Comment: Then get all the tags and filter per matched string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you seeing with `bs.find_all(string='SHIFTER')` aren't strings (as `str`), but instances of `bs4.element.NavigableString`, so you can use standard BeautifulSoup methods on them:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.betts.com.au/item/39613-shifter.html?colour=black'
bs = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, features="html.parser")

for text in bs.find_all(string='SHIFTER'):
    print(text.parent)
```

Prints:

```
<span itemprop="name">SHIFTER</span>
<h1 class="wdj-item-descrpition-h1">SHIFTER</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, this info "aren't strings (as str), but instances of bs4.element.NavigableString" is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is the expected behaviour.

You can see [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument).

> With string you can search for strings instead of tags.

Comment: Do you know a way to get the text, when matching only on a string/text value?